# Find Active Index From Array (Logic)

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time with this one. I'm using Javascript.

I have a textarea that's detecting the `@` input and storing it's position in an array.

```
var input = "@a @b @c" //textarea
var indexes = [1, 4, 7];
```

Now on each new `input` I want to find out the active index by looking at the `caretPos`

```
indexes.forEach(function(value, i){
    if (input.substr(value - 1, 1) !== '@') {
        indexes.splice(i, 1);
    }
    if (caretPos == value || caretPos > value) {
        activeIndex = value;
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing one check but I don't know how to implement. This code works as long as you're going backwards with the `caretPos` but once you go forward it stops working.

Edit: In case its not clear. If the `caretPos` is `5` the `activeIndex` would be `4`.

Comment: Hello can you please add your code in jsfiddle so i will debug it

Comment: Hello you want to match the indexes with the character position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to find the index of the first @ symbol to the left of the caretPos.
The reason your current setup does not work is that you are changing the indexes array while you are looping over it. `index.splice()` changes the indexes. And this is dangerous/ not good practice when you loop over an array.

And you don't really need your indexes array to achieve what you want.

If you do:

```
activeIndex = input.slice(0,caretpos).lastIndexOf('@') +1;
```

You should get the right result.

- `slice()` cuts everything from caretpos out of your input string (without changing original input string)
- `lastIndexOf()` finds the last occurrance of the @ symbol (and adds 1 because this is what you are looking for).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. Here's the JSFiddle of a working example https://jsfiddle.net/fp1gy10a/2/